# Setting no controls in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to set that `JFrame` will not have any controls (no close, minimize, maximize), I remember something `decorate`..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [public void setUndecorated(boolean undecorated)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29)

> Disables or enables decorations for this frame. This method can only
>   be called while the frame is not displayable.

BTW, to be honest, I forgot the method name, but I just wrote *"remove buttons from JFrame"* in google and found the answer. Doing a very small research can sometimes really help.

Comment: [setUndecorated in jdk7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29)